# Get links for a card with puppetear

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

i want to get the element a off the class card-action with puppeteear, its a div with a list of col s12 m6 how i can do that ?

```
<div class="row post-row">
<div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card large xp-post" id="p29710684">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <img class="activator lazyloaded" src="/xp_data/105255/29710684/thumb.jpg"
                data-src="/105255/29710684/thumb.jpg" alt="plap">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">plap <i
                    class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
            <br><span style="font-size: 85%;" class="grey-text post-time">2019-09-04 18:15</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
            <a href="105255/29710684/08-29-2019_0955PM_756_531.png" target="_blank">Post file</a>
            <i class="material-icons right xp-flag" title="Flag this post" data-pid="29710684">flag</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6"></div>
    <div class="col s12 m6"></div>
</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: You can use page.evaluate function to accomplish it

Answer (score 0):

After importing puppeteer use the below, it should print out all the hrefs in the console.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

 puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => { 
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('<url_here>'); 
let selector= "element_id_or_selector"; 
await page.evaluate((sel) => { 
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel); 
for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++){ console.log(elements[i].href); }, selector);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With puppeteer you can use the usual javascript which you would use in the browser/on the page. A script must be run inside of `page.evaluate` method and it must `return` what it finds:

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

```
puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://example.com');

  const href = await page.evaluate(function(){
      // if there is only one link of the its kind
      return document.querySelector(".card-action a").href
  });

  await browser.close();
});
```

And if there a lot of rows with links that you're after:

```
  const hrefs = await page.evaluate(function(){
      return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".card-action a")).map(function(link){
          return link.href;
      });
  });
```